# Outlook 2011 saves to draft instead of sending

Tags: mac-osx, exchange, exchange-2010, outlook, hosted-exchange

Every now and again, (once a day for some users), emails get saved in the draft folder and not sent. There is no message to show this when it happens, just a few hours later, you notice unread messages in your drafts folder.

I'm trying to find out why this happens, as some of the messages cannot be sent by simply clicking opening them and clicking send.

Some assistance would be appreciated.